# How to do 'Order by Desc' when Primary key is Guid and there is no time stamp column?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm working on an unusual table design. The primary key datatype is `Guid` and there is no date/time column in table. How I can order results descending?

Note that I'm not allowed to add a new column in table. Unfortunately other columns also have some flags which cannot be used for ordering data in descending order.

I need to get some of the last inserted rows.

Comment: Mitch Wheat can add a new column

Comment: is GUID a randomly generated value or it is incremental in some sense?

Comment: The real question would be "order by descending? according to what?" You need some sort of data to tell what row was "first" and "last", since data in a table is, by definition, unordered.

Comment: Then you should review the table relation to get some hints

Comment: The physical insertion order isn't a property that SQL Server records or in any way attempts to preserve. If you want this information (or any close analogue to it), you have to create a column to record this information and ensure that it gets populated. And if you've already got data in your table, there's no reliable way to "recover" such information.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that there is no way to get the last record inserted into a table with SQL Server unless you go through the transaction logs or can order by a sequential column of some sort.

[See here for further details.](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/8704ad36-e9d9-41ab-9ded-881463e81e6c/select-the-last-records-inserted-to-table)

You may get lucky and your GUID has a date/time component or other similar sequential pattern, but without knowing how you're generating the GUIDs it's hard to say.

Answer (score 0):

For your database, when inserting new rows you must use NEWSEQUENTIALID. Then you will be able to use the ORDER BY [GUID Column name] DESC to get rows in order of insertion. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms189786.aspx

The only problem is when you restart the server it may start from a lower GUID. This maybe a problem or not depending on your circumstances.